# Would an API key be exposed through a private docker container image on DockerHub?

Tags: angular, docker, dockerhub

For example if an containerised angular application within a kubernetes cluster is deployed will users be able to access the code and subsequently a subscription key for an API? What would be best practice for protecting your subscription keys / authentication details etc.?

edit - Specified subscription keys.

Comment: What API key do you mean?

Comment: Question updated to specificy subscription keys for APIs

Comment: If the docker image can be downloaded, its files can be dissected and any information inside can be extracted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if I'm understanding your question in full, so let me rephrase what I believe you're asking:

- You are building a Docker image, in which you are hard coding an API key, so that when you run the image - the API key is already setup.
- You are publishing your image to Docker Hub - but you are not listing the image publicly, it is a private image for your account.

So, no - your API key is not exposed in this case, but it is not good practice.

Firstly - You are trusting Docker Hub. If your account is compromised, or Docker Hub is compromised (Which has [happened before](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19763413)) then your API key is vulnerable. Slim chance, which leads me to the primary reason why it's a bad idea:

You [should not store configuration](https://12factor.net/config) in your application. It's bad practice and doesn't let your application flow properly between environments. You usually want separate API keys for development, testing, and production environments. And you want to be able to easily use the same image and change this simply by adjusting an environment variable.

As for protecting your authentication keys - Put them into environment variables, or use a service for grabbing keys during run-time (eg: Hashicorp Vault, AWS Parameter Store, etc.)

Comment: Kubernetes has specific stuff for this even, the Secrets system.

Comment: @coderanger Not a k8s user, but yeah - that works too! Same with swarm secrets